# How do you access the DLC content in Hollow Knight?

Tags: hollow-knight

What are the steps to access each DLC content in Hollow Knight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the Grimm Troupe DLC needs specific activation:

> In order to start the quest the Player must first travel to the Howling Cliffs and go through a breakable wall. Then find "The corpse of a large bug" and use the dream nail on it, allowing the player to turn on the torch thus activating the content, that will spawn on Dirtmouth.
>
> [image]

The rest are new additions (like bosses, charms...) and fixes to the game.

Find more information in [the wiki page about DLCs](http://hollowknight.wikia.com/wiki/Additional_Content).

Comment: One could argue to "access" a new area one must know where it's located.

Comment: No new areas added by the DLC's so far, apart from a new stag station.

Comment: Hidden Dreams does add a new dream boss, though, so it might be a good idea to mention where said boss is.

Comment: There are a lot of additions, apart from those two bosses, IMHO it doesn't make sense to detail everything in a very long post. That is why I've added the reference link to the page that details the changelogs

Comment: Sense or not, that seems what OP was asking

Comment: Disagree. I don't think he asks for every location of every new addition, but what to do to be able to use the new content. If you're right, the access is too broad and should be closed (IMO), if not, this answer should be enough. Anyway, it makes more sense to wait until the OP (and not us) specifies about his desires, instead of discussing here